# Fluent NHibernate ISessionFactory for reading, writing and updating database

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Sorry! I am messing up by asking simple questions.
I have a very simple Store object that I am going to store the database, reading, updating, etc. It works fine for the first time but also reading is fine if I have the current session factory.
Now if I reopen my sample app for reading the database then I see the problem. For reading, it uses the same InitializeSessionFactory() so my database becomes empty.  How can I modify the InitializeSessionFactory() so it will work independently for writing, updating, and deleting individual records?

public class NHibernateHelper
{
private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

```
private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
{
    get
    {
        if (_sessionFactory == null)
            InitializeSessionFactory();
        return _sessionFactory;
    }
}

private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
{
    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql7.ConnectionString(@"Server=(local);initial catalog=MyDatabase; user=my_user_id;password=my_password;").ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Store>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}

public static ISession OpenSession()
{
    return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Database expert nor a Fluent Nhibernate veteran.  After trying and playing around I found a solution like this. So I was misusing it. It seems it is working (not sure if there is any regression issue though)

```
   //.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
```